# Is there any option in intro.js to make highlighted text or image clear

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic4, intro.js

I am trying to implement intro.js in ionic 4 but the highlighted text is not visible

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chMOP.png)

here how i implemented the code in angular 7.

```
intro() {
let intro = introJs.introJs();
intro.setOptions({
  exitOnOverlayClick: false,
  showStepNumbers: false,
  showBullets: false,
  overlayOpacity: 0.8,
  doneLabel: "GOT IT",
  nextLabel: "GOT IT",
  steps: [
    {
      element: '#search-img',
      intro: "Search here by accounts, contacts, etc.",
      position: 'top',
    }, {
      element: '#search-text',
      intro: "Search here by accounts, contacts, etc.",
      position: 'top',
    },
    {
      element: '#search-box',
      intro: "Search here by accounts, contacts, etc.",
      position: 'middle',
    },
    {
      element: '#profile',
      intro: "Click on profile icon to view your DPN account & saved 
      list",
      position: 'bottom',
      floatVArrow: 'right'
    }
    ]
   });
   intro.start();
   }
```

Comment: Not sure how you expect anyone to help you with this when you haven't shown us any of your existing HTML, CSS or JS

Comment: its simple intro.js link    https://introjs.com/

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow please read this information carefully -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: it is library and i have shared the link of library

Comment: Everything looks ok on the library website, so the problem is with your app, with your css indeed. Without it, no one can help you, so please add more code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the `highlightClass` attribute for that particular step so that the step points to a class (I called it `.my-bespoke-class`) where you use CSS to do whatever you like to the highlight eg changing the opacity or colour.

I would need to check but I am pretty sure you can change the `overlayOpacity` for a step too (you certainly can in Shepherd).

```js
let intro = introJs();

intro.setOptions({
  exitOnOverlayClick: false,
  showStepNumbers: false,
  showBullets: false,
  overlayOpacity: 0.8,
  doneLabel: "GOT IT",
  nextLabel: "GOT IT",
  steps: [
    {
      element: '#search-text',
      intro: "Search here by accounts, contacts, etc.",
      position: 'top',
      highlightClass: '.my-bespoke-class',
      overlayOpacity: '1'
    }
    ]
   });

intro.start();
```

```css
#search-text{
  width: 300px:
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.my-bespoke-class{
  background: orange;
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/intro.js-mit@3.0.0/introjs.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/intro.js-mit@3.0.0/intro.min.js"></script>

<html>
<body>
<div id="search-text">This is the target element</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Further information can be found in the official docs which you can find at https://introjs.com/docs/

Comment: Thank you for this but can u please give me css which u are using for ".my-bespoke-class" please

Comment: actually i waant to highlight the element as shown in introjs demos can u help me iin achieving it

Comment: @Milliways I am sorry that I have upset you somehow. My edits were intended to help the community. If you have taken offence with something I have done then commenting on an unrelated answer on a different SE site is probably not the way to go about it. You may wish to restrict your comments to the topic of the question/answer.

Comment: @rchauhan I am finishing my lunchbreak just now but will mockup a demo for you later tonight.